# javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'tname' not found on type java.lang.String

Tags: java, jsp, struts, jstl, el

I was using scriptlets earlier, but now I switched to the mvc. I am not able to retrieve values on to the JSP page and getting errors:

```
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'tname' not found on type java.lang.String
```

Code of the Bean:

```
public class regForm extends org.apache.struts.validator.ValidatorForm implements Iprafunctions {

    private String tname = null;
    private String tfee = null;

    public String getTfee() {
        return tfee;
    }

    public void setTfee(String tfee) {
        this.tfee = tfee;
    }

    public String getTname() {
        return tname;
    }

    public void setTname(String tname) {
        this.tname = tname;
    }
    public regForm() {
        super();
    }
}
```

Action controller:

```
public ActionForward mvc(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
        HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws Exception {
    regForm reg = (regForm) form;
    String sql = "Select tname,tfee from addtest order by tname";
    ResultSet rs = SQLC.getData(sql, null);
    Collection myBeans = new ArrayList();
    while (rs.next()) {
        String testname = rs.getString("tname");
        String testfee = rs.getString("tfee");
        reg.setTname(testname);
        reg.setTfee(testfee);
        myBeans.add(reg.getTname());
        myBeans.add(reg.getTfee());
    }
    request.setAttribute("myBeans", myBeans);
    return mapping.findForward(SUCCESS);
}
```

Access in JSP Page

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<table>
    <tr><td>Name</td><td>Fee</td></tr>
    <c:forEach var="reg" items="${myBeans}">
        <tr>
            <td><c:out value="${reg.tname}"></c:out></td>
            <td><c:out value="${reg.tfee}"></c:out></td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
</table>
```

Comment: i have a quick question, i haven't worked with struts but should you not add the attribute to the response. i saw you are adding it in the request.

Comment: @raddy no, attributes are set to request for internal communication and then request is just forwarded

Comment: because we are sending request and setting the value of attribute then we will get the response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are adding the names and the fee directly to the arraylist, but you should be adding the whole `regForm` object in the arraylist.

Instead of the below code

```
myBeans.add(reg.getTname());
myBeans.add(reg.getTfee());
```

you need to do like

```
myBeans.add(reg);
```

moreover dont use the same object that you got from the form. Try to create new objects and add in the arraylist and try to use generics.

**EDIT:**

```
while (rs.next()) {
        String testname = rs.getString("tname");
        String testfee = rs.getString("tfee");
        regForm beanObject = new regForm();
        beanObject.setTname(testname);
        beanObject.setTfee(testfee);
        myBeans.add(beanObject);
    }
```

Comment: The output is like this in vertical manner here not showing properly but hope you get this
Name Fee  
Reproductive Hormones  50.00  
Reproductive Hormones  50.00  
Reproductive Hormones  50.00  
Reproductive Hormones  50.00  
Reproductive Hormones  50.00  
Reproductive Hormones  50.00  
Reproductive Hormones  50.00  
Reproductive Hormones  50.00

Comment: please see my new edit. this is the reason i mentioned that you need to create new objects for each record and add that to the list. In your earlier code you were using the reference from the form and you were setting in that same object. Since you are changing the values in the reference its getting updated for all the objects in the list. hope this helps.

Answer (score 5):

Actually you are adding strings in your `Collection` and you are trying to invoke

`getTName()`  by `${reg.tname}`

Either add whole bean to your collection or just replace JSTL with `${reg}`

Comment: if I replace JSTL with ${reg} then the output is like that  

   Name         Fee  
   Ammonia  Ammonia  
   420.00  420.00  Amylase  Amylase
   250.00  250.00
   Anti D Titre  Anti D Titre
  350.00  350.00

Comment: It is because you added whole bean now, please reread my answer either just make it `${reg}` or if you add beans to collection then don't change the JSP stuff

Comment: this is the output when i had only do change in JSP page.... and when I add whole bean to collection and no change in JSP page then i am getting the output written a comment in above answer

Comment: then you are setting wrong content in attribute, try to debug

Comment: the attributes are fine.... as u saw in above output the same tname and tfee is printed 10 times instead of different tname's and tfee's