# ArrayList of Bean..How to access the property of a bean using EL in jsp..? Throws NotFoundError exception

Tags: java, jsp, arraylist, jstl, javabeans

I have an arraylist of employeebean resultEmployeeList set in request scope..
I don't know if i was doing it the right way.. But here is the jstl code used in jsp..

```
<c:forEach var="element" items="${resultEmployeeList} ">
            <tr>

                <td>
                ${element.empId}
                </td>
                <td> ${element.empname}</td>


            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
```

when i try to access empId property of employeebean, it shows this error

```
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'empid' not found on type java.lang.String
```

Here is the employeebean

```
public class EmployeeBean {

private int empId;
private String empname;
private boolean exceptionExist;
public EmployeeBean() {
}

public int getEmpId() {
    return empId;
}

public void setEmpId(int empId) {

    this.empId = empId;
}

public EmployeeBean(int empId, String empname) {
    this.empId = empId;
    this.empname = empname;
}

public String getEmpname() {
    return empname;
}

public void setEmpname(String empname) {
    this.empname = empname;
}

public boolean exceptionExist(){
return true;
}
```

}

This is where i put the resultEmployeeList

```
public boolean getEmployeesIn(ArrayList<Integer> empids,HttpServletRequest request) {
    ArrayList<EmployeeBean> employeeList=new ArrayList<EmployeeBean>();
    Iterator empidIterator=empids.iterator();
    while(empidIterator.hasNext()){

        employeeList.add(eObject.getEmployee((Integer)empidIterator.next()));
    }
    if(employeeList.isEmpty())
        return false;
    else{
    request.setAttribute("resultEmployeeList", employeeList);
    }
    return true;
```

Wherein eObject.getEmployee(..) calls this method..

```
 public EmployeeBean getEmployee(int empId) {

    EmployeeBean eb = new EmployeeBean();
    try {

        String query = "select * from empschema.employee where empid=?";
        ps = con.prepareStatement(query);
        ps.setInt(1, empId);
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

        if (!rs.next()) {
            eb=null;
            return eb;

        } else {

                eb.setEmpId(rs.getInt(1));
                eb.setEmpname(rs.getString(2));

        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(EmployeeDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return eb;

}
```

Comment: Can you post that code where you put list in request scope?

Comment: ${resultEmployeeList} this list in request scope... I hope you are setting in the controller

Comment: replace ${resultEmployeeList} with ${requestScope.resultEmployeeList} and check

Comment: @niiraj874u  posted the code..

Comment: surendhar, have you tried using ${requestScope.resultEmployeeList}

Comment: @niiraj874u Yea.. tried.. but didnt work out..

Comment: Try iterating the list alone like this `<td>${element}</td>`

Comment: @san krish this is what i got when iterating 
[com.app.beans.EmployeeBean@1837f798  [com.app.beans.EmployeeBean@1837f798
com.app.beans.EmployeeBean@2602894]  com.app.beans.EmployeeBean@2602894]

Comment: Can't get you . did you get the same thing i posted without rendering ?

Comment: Why dont you try with `c:out` tag ?

Comment: ${element} is employeebean..hence when i used it in jstl, it showed the reference number.. but my problem is, i couldn't do this ${element.empId}

Comment: @sankrish tried that as well.. it showed the same error  javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'empId' not found on type java.lang.String
 javax.el.BeanELResolver$BeanProperties.get(BeanELResolver.java:237)
 javax.el.BeanELResolver$BeanProperties.access$400(BeanELResolver.java:214)
 javax.el.BeanELResolver.property(BeanELResolver.java:325)
 javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:85)
 org.apache.jasper.el.JasperELResolver.getValue(JasperELResolver.java:104)

Comment: I guess your way of adding the objects into the list seems incorrect

Comment: You need to add the object into the array list like this `employeeList.add(eb)` to access the getters from the bean

Comment: Nope..still it has to work..

Comment: NO you shouldnt see the [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10855288/javax-el-propertynotfoundexception-property-tname-not-found-on-type-java-lang) and also this [one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13807683/property-someproperty-not-found-on-type-java-lang-string)

Comment: Note the line employeeList.add(eObject.getEmployee()), where eObject.getEmployee() returns EmployeeBean itself.. Not a string or integer[the ones mentioned in ur link]

Comment: Are you sure the error is occurring in the code snippet you have shared? Can you share rest of the code(if any) in your jsp?

Comment: @Priyesh that's all i had in jsp.. c:foreach was inside the body tag..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have pasted the code as is, then there is an extra space in `items="${resultEmployeeList} "` after `${resultEmployeeList}`. That can cause the variable `element` to be treated as a String instead of the actual type.